# Fixar barra de Menu no Topo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou trabalhando em um site que o HTML do Menu não é alterável. Eu quero que quando o usuário rolar o scroll do mouse até a barra de menu, ela se torne fixa no topo da página, respeitando a distância de outra barra que está funcionando e já se fixa automaticamente.

HTML do MENU (Não alterável):

```
<nav class="menu_component" id="component_37548">
<div class="menu-head">
    <span>
        Menu
    </span>
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin-r" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner">
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="menu-panel">
    <menu class="expanded hamburger-menu">
        <li id="menu_item_39037" class="sub">
            <a alt="O SIENPRO" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                O SIENPRO
            </a>
            <menu class="submenu">
                <li id="menu_item_41614" class="">
                    <a alt="SOBRE" title="" target="" class="" href="/p/21374-sobre-o-sienpro">
                        SOBRE
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu_item_39038" class="">
                    <a alt="COMIT&Ecirc;" title="" target="" class="" href="/p/23834-comite-2018">
                        COMIT&Ecirc;
                    </a>
                </li>
            </menu>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_41615" class="">
            <a alt="TEMA" title="" target="" class="" href="https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/#tema">
                TEMA
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_41616" class="">
            <a alt="PRINCIPAIS DATAS" title="" target="" class="" href="https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/#datas">
                PRINCIPAIS DATAS
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_39040" class="sub">
            <a alt="EDI&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES SIENPRO" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                EDI&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES SIENPRO
            </a>
            <menu class="submenu">
                <li id="menu_item_41593" class="">
                    <a alt="I SIENPRO - 2017" title="" target="" class="" href="/p/23811-i-sienpro-2017">
                        I SIENPRO - 2017
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu_item_41605" class="">
                    <a alt="II SIENPRO - 2018" title="" target="" class="" href="/p/23814-ii-sienpro-2018">
                        II SIENPRO - 2018
                    </a>
                </li>
            </menu>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_39041" class="">
            <a alt="CONTATO" title="" target="" class="" href="https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/#contato">
                CONTATO
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_41617" class="sub">
            <a alt="ARTIGOS" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                ARTIGOS
            </a>
            <menu class="submenu">
                <li id="menu_item_41618" class="">
                    <a alt="REGRAS PARA SUBMISS&Atilde;O" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                        REGRAS PARA SUBMISS&Atilde;O
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu_item_41619" class="">
                    <a alt="ORIENTA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O PARA APRESENTA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                        ORIENTA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O PARA APRESENTA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O
                    </a>
                </li>
            </menu>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_41620" class="">
            <a alt="PROGRAMA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                PROGRAMA&Ccedil;&Atilde;O
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu_item_41621" class="">
            <a alt="LOCAL" title="" target="" class="empty-href">
                LOCAL
            </a>
        </li>
    </menu>
</div>
```

CSS da variável de fixação:

```
.fixar{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 37px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Javascript para tentar fixar o menu:

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    var offset = $('.menu_component').offset().top;
    var nav = $('.menu_component');

$(document).on('scroll', function () {
        if (offset <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            nav.addClass('fixar');
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('fixar');
        }
    });

});
```

Pensei que estava certo o Javascript, mas não está funcionando de maneira alguma. Link para acessar o site: https://sienpro.catalao.ufg.br/

Não sei se é classe que estou tentando alterar que está errada, se é classe da `<nav>`, da `<div>`, ou do `<menu>` que eu tenho que alterar com o javascript, 
 ou se tem que ser uma cascata entre todas elas.

Comment: Pelo visto você não carregou a biblioteca do jQuery no código

Comment: @LeandroAngelo A pergunta dele contém o código quase igual ao da resposta, o problema dela é apenas a falta da incorporação do `Jquery`

Comment: Alguém pode me dizer como fazer isso? kkkk Sou totalmente noob em Javascript, nem css e html eu sei direito. Aprendi copiando e colando de um site pro outro.

Comment: Ah obrigado, resolvi colocando <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> antes do </head>.

Comment: Se alguém precisar foi isso aí. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jovem vc pode resolver isso apenas com CSS.

Vc pode colocar `position:fixed` e `top:0` na primeira Barra e na segunda usar Barra usar `position:sticky` e `top:50px` *(50px é a altura da primeira Barra, assim uma não fica por cima da outra)*

Veja um exemplo simples de como fica o resultado.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 80px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
}
.cor {
    font-size: 32px;
    background-color: red;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 50px;
}
.topo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="topo">Barra #1</h1>
<section>
    <h3>Teste barra</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h1 class="cor">Barra #2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium iste quia provident nemo dolore assumenda illo commodi! Repellendus quibusdam hic doloribus commodi, quis culpa possimus incidunt perspiciatis aperiam quidem.</p>
</section>
```