# Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma no CSS pra identificar a rolagem do scroll

Tags: css, rolamento

Tenho uma pagina onde o cabeçalho fica no top:0 position: absolute, porem queria que ela mudasse para position: fixed, caso o usuário role o scroll pra cima.

**Exemplo:** no topo da pagina o menu vai ficar no topo mesmo, depois de 800px para baixo, sempre q ele tentar rolar pra cima (buscando o cabeçalho novamente) ele aparecera no topo da pagina fixado. Assim o usuário não precisaria ir até o topo da pagina para encontrar o cabeçalho.

**Obs.:** *caso não tenha como fazer isso no CSS, pode mandar uma solução da forma q achar mais pratica.*

**Exemplo de como esta o menu:**

```css
container1 {
 position: absolute;
 right: 84px;
 bottom: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
#menu {
 height: 57px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
 margin-top: 0px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 1120px;
 margin-left: -1%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 102%;
 z-index: 999;
}
#logo_s_frase_menu {
 width: 86.94px;
 height: 36.54px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 120px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
#home_menu{
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 border-top-left-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
}
#home_menu:hover{
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#home_menu:focus{
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#comofunciona_menu {
 height: 41px;
 width: 208px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#comofunciona_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#comofunciona_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#quemsomos_menu {
 height: 41px;
 width: 180px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#quemsomos_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#quemsomos_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#contato_menu {
 width: 147px;
 height: 41px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 36.5px;
 padding-right: 36.5px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#contato_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#contato_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#entrar_menu {
 width: 133px;
 height: 41px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #c4c4c4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#entrar_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#entrar_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
```

```html
<header id="menu">
<a id="logo_menu" href="index.php"><img id="logo_s_frase_menu"  src="img/logo_s_frase.svg"></a>
<container1 id="caminho_menu">
<a id="home_menu" href=""><cxsb>HOME</cxsb></a>
<a id="comofunciona_menu"><cxsb>COMO FUNCIONA</cxsb></a>
<a id="quemsomos_menu"><cxsb>QUEM SOMOS</cxsb></a>
<a id="contato_menu"><cxsb>CONTATO</cxsb></a>
<a id="entrar_menu"><cxsb>ENTRAR</cxsb></a>
</container1>
</header>
1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
```

Comment: Já adiantando, só com CSS não tem como...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fixar barra de Menu no Topo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282389/fixar-barra-de-menu-no-topo)

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo. [Como referencia usei esse artigo](https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima, deixei uns comments no código caso te interesse.

```js
// esconde Header no scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function () {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Assegura que o escroll seja maior que delta
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // Se scrolled down passar de navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // Isso é necessário para vc não ver o que está por tras navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #000 100%);
    height: 2000px;
}

footer {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<header class="nav-down">
    menu.
</header>
<main>
    body.
</main>
<footer>
     footer.
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar JavaScript para isso (apenas com CSS não é possível). Você ativa a função apenas quando ultrapassar 800 pixels de scroll, e toda vez que você subir a página o menu é mostrado (`fixed`) e ao descer ele volta pro início novamente (`absolute`):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var fixa, pos;
   window.onscroll = function(){
      var scrl = window.scrollY;
      if(scrl > 800 && !fixa) fixa = true;
      document.querySelector("#menu").style.position = fixa && pos > scrl ? "fixed" : "absolute";
      pos = scrl;
   }
});
```

```css
container1 {
 position: absolute;
 right: 84px;
 bottom: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 17px;
}
#menu {
 height: 57px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
 margin-top: 0px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 min-width: 1120px;
 margin-left: -1%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 102%;
 z-index: 999;
}
#logo_s_frase_menu {
 width: 86.94px;
 height: 36.54px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 120px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
#home_menu{
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 border-top-left-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
}
#home_menu:hover{
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#home_menu:focus{
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#comofunciona_menu {
 height: 41px;
 width: 208px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#comofunciona_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#comofunciona_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#quemsomos_menu {
 height: 41px;
 width: 180px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#quemsomos_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#quemsomos_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#contato_menu {
 width: 147px;
 height: 41px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 36.5px;
 padding-right: 36.5px;
 color: #C4C4C4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#contato_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#contato_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#entrar_menu {
 width: 133px;
 height: 41px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 35px;
 padding-right: 35px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #c4c4c4;
 margin-left: -4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#entrar_menu:hover {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
#entrar_menu:focus {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #444CF0;
 color: #444CF0;
}
```

```html
<header id="menu">
   <a id="logo_menu" href="index.php"><img id="logo_s_frase_menu"  src="img/logo_s_frase.svg"></a>
   <container1 id="caminho_menu">
      <a id="home_menu" href=""><cxsb>HOME</cxsb></a>
      <a id="comofunciona_menu"><cxsb>COMO FUNCIONA</cxsb></a>
      <a id="quemsomos_menu"><cxsb>QUEM SOMOS</cxsb></a>
      <a id="contato_menu"><cxsb>CONTATO</cxsb></a>
      <a id="entrar_menu"><cxsb>ENTRAR</cxsb></a>
   </container1>
</header>
a<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
```